# How to pass variables between processes with multiprocessing Queue()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm trying to run two separate python processes in parallel with a need for the processes to pass data back and forth. The MCV I've included is reflective of the structure of the underlying packages I'm using - I was hoping a solution using multiprocessing would remove the need to radically alter the underlying code of either.

To summarise the interaction,  1) the child process starts and adds an initial value to a queue 2) The parent process should then take the value, do something, and return the new value to another queue which the 3) child process reads and prints. (In reality, both these processes are self-contained loops which will run for thousands of iterations passing data back and forth... hopefully)

However, everything hangs waiting for the parent process to start (i.e., after step 1). Does the child process block the parent from running?

I've trawled through the many similar, yet not quite the same, scenarios on here as well as the multiprocessing docs and a number of tutorials and can't wrap my head around exactly what is causing the problem.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def sub_func(x,q1,q2):

    queue1 = q1
    queue2 = q2

    y = x*x
    queue1.put(y)
    #print(queue1.qsize())#prints 1 as expected

    while queue2.empty():
        sleep(0.01) # Hangs here

    z = queue2.get()
    print(z)

def start_sub(q1,q2):

    sub_func(5,q1,q2)

class parent():

    def main_func():

        while q1.empty():
            sleep(0.01)

        y = q1.get()
        z = y*y
        q2.put(z)


if __name__=='__main__': # Is this necessary?

    q1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q2 = multiprocessing.Queue()

    subprocess = Process(target=start_sub(q1,q2))
    subprocess.start()
    print('subprocess started') # Doesn't get executed
    parent.main_func() # Does main need q1,q2 passed?
```

I've annotated the code to include (what I think) is happening i.e., the child process is started successfully but hangs waiting for the parent process to add items to the queue (q2). It seems the parent process doesn't even begin.

Seeing as I need both processes to be running simultaneously, using .join() to wait for the child process to end wont work.

Would really appreciate any advice on how to fix this or if I'm on the wrong path entirely perhaps a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Not sure how wise it is to define a class called `main`. Nor am I sure you can call its `main_func()` method without creating an object of that class first... but I know little about Python. And I think you'd have to declare `q1` and `q2` as `global` in that class to see the queues everyone else is using.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Mark, I've changed it now to parent(): instead of main(): The issue unfortunately persists. You could well be right about declaring the queues as global variables in the parent class too - unfortunately the parent process isn't even being executed at the moment so I can't yet check. I look at the (plentiful) examples, I look at my code and I'm not seeing where I'm going wrong.